# The result type 'System.Tuple`3[System.Guid,System.Int32,System.String]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, tuples

Is it possible to read tuple list from `ObjectContext` object?

I have database query something like this, inside a stored procedure

```
SELECT 
    T.Id as Item1, -- this is guid
    T.WorkflowId AS Item2, -- this is int
    T.ActionName AS Item3 -- this is string
FROM 
    MyTable T
```

And c# code I am trying to read it like this

```
var command = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "[SEQUOIA].[GetWriteOffRequestDetails]";
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context);
context.Database.Connection.Open();

if (reader.NextResult())
{
    // this line is giving error, so basically where it is trying to read/translate the result
    List<Tuple<Guid, int, string>> requestItemActions = objectContext.ObjectContext.Translate<Tuple<Guid, int, string>>(reader).Select(x => new Tuple<Guid, int, string>(x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3)).ToList();
}
```

But it is throwing this exception

> The result type
>   'System.Tuple`3[System.Guid,System.Int32,System.String]' may not be
>   abstract and must include a default constructor.

So is it even possible to read tuples like this?

If yes, could anybody point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `tuple` in this case because `tuple` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-3?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't have default constructor (parameter-less constructor) .net framework use reflection to create this type **automatically**  so it should have default constructor.

so solution in this case is creating class that contains these three properties and use it instead of tuple

```
public class DataClass
{

    public Guid Item1 { get; set; }
    public int Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}




List<DataClass> requestItemActions = objectContext.ObjectContext.Translate<DataClass>(reader).ToList();
```

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid this solution, otherwise yes this is the standard solution.

Comment: the issue is you should use type has default constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
objectContext.ObjectContext.Select(x => 
   ValueTuple.Create(x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3))
.ToList(); }
```

Comment: Can you try ValueTuple.Create?

Comment: Yeah, it is loading results. It is working even without the select part with `ValueTuple`, so this alone is loading rows `objectContext.ObjectContext.Translate<ValueTuple<Guid, int, string>>(reader).ToList();`. The only problem now is that it is not loading values, so all Item1, 2 and 3 are empty but it does load the number of objects for the number of rows with all empty values. I am trying to figure out what could be the reason. You have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I have no idea but my answer was suggested by EF team, may be empty constructor isn’t initializing fields.

Comment: I tried both, the empty constructor as well as the one that you suggested but both has the same problem that they do load the result set for each row but with all empty values. Let's see if I can figure out the reason then I will let you know and will also select your answer as the correct answer :)

Comment: Don’t use translate, just use select as I have updated my answer

Comment: That code will not even compile. There is no method `Select` in `ObjectContext`, how will it know to which object it should translate result to before selecting. `Translate` is a must thing